Counting process approach in survival analysis with non-contiguous intervals?
I am setting up a Cox Proportional Hazards model in R to analyze survival time until a recurrence event occurs. Each case can experience multiple recurrence events, therefore I decided to emply the counting process approach, recording time_start and time_stop for each "survival" interval.
In the counting process approach of survival analysis for recurrent events, all examples I can find record time to the first event in a given subject, and then the dataset continues directly at this point in time (3 months in my example) with the time period until the second event.



id
tstart (in months)
tstop (in months)




1
0
3


1
3
7



However, in my data the event of recurrence covers some time period itself, and therefore the starting time of the second interval is not identical anymore to the stopping time of the first interval.



id
tstart (in months)
tstop (in months)




1
0
3


1
6
10



My question is, can the Cox model in the counting process approach handle this time gap between the two intervals, where subjects are actually at risk of experiencing the event? Do I have to undertake any steps to account for that?
The alternative approach I have been thinking about is a "standard" Cox model like for single event data but with robust standard errors for subjects & strata for previous event yes/no (as I have no specific hypothesis about order of events).
Any guidance much appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
